# Url not showing up in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls

I recently decided to use biblatex instead of bibtex to do my citations. One of the problems I have been facing is that the urls for the webpages are not showing up in my bibliography. First time I tried running it, an error message asked my to include the hyperref package. I did that and it executed but the bibliography had "Web" written at the end and it was linked to the url. I switched the hyperref package with url, hoping it would change the "Web" to the actual url. instead, it kept the "Web" and now its not even linked to the webpage. What I want is for the full url to be displayed and for that to be linked to the webpage. Is it possible to do this? If so, can someone please help me out?

*note: I am using the mla style for everything

EDIT Here is the MWE:

This is the latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=mla]{biblatex}

\urlstyle{sf}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

    Some sample text.\cite{test}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and this is the the bib file:

```
@online{test,
    author = {Sample Author},
    title = {Sample Title},
    journal = {Sample Journal},
    date = {2016-12-14},
    url = {http://www.sample.com}
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you can provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) we will be bale to reproduce your problem more efficiently and investigate it in more detail.

Comment: Update `biblatex-mla` and use the new `style=mla-new`.

Comment: If you use the old style, try the option `noremoteinfo=false`.

Comment: I tried adding 'noremoteinfo=false'. It puts the link in but it also keeps the the word "Web" and it puts the link in between "<" ">". This is not the standard mla citation format. My school won't accept it.

Comment: This probably was MLA v. 7. If you want the newer version 8 (where the output probably looks like you want), you need to update `biblatex-mla` and use `mla-new`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to follow the 8th edition of the MLA style. In order to use this style you will have to update your `biblatex-mla` package and use the new style `mla-new`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=mla-new]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\urlstyle{sf}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Some sample text.\cite{ctan}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

In the old style `mla` which follows the 7th edition, you can use the option

```
noremoteinfo=false
```